# How to read the previous 2 lines when reading through a text file

Tags: java, file

I am currently working on a program that reads through a text file and prints different lines depending on what the previous line consists of. For example if the previous line was an integer, then I print a different variation of the current line. How can I check to see whether the previous line was an integer without going through the file two lines at a time?

Here is the code so far.

```
 public void workThroughFile(String filename) {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (isInteger(line) == false && line.contains("?") == true) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            if (isInteger(line) == false && line.contains("?") == false) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            if (isInteger(line) == true) {

            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Did not quite work this time.");
    }
}
```

Comment: it will be nice if you could paste what you have worked so far

Comment: If what your program does depends upon the prior line, I think you're going to find that the simplest way to manage that is to keep the prior read line as you go. You're just reading one line at a time, but maintaining a "state". There are ways to seek back in the file, but it would be more cumbersome to do that. Your question title, by the way, implies you are wanting to look at the 2 previous lines, rather than 1 previous line. So your question is a little confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep track of state.  For example if you want to look at the last two lines and keep track of if they were ints or not you have 4 possible states: neither were ints, last was int, 2nd last was int, or both were ints. Just make something (ex. boolean wasLastLineInt) to keep track of the state and update it as you read lines.  Booleans are probably the easiest way to keep track of the state.

```
wasLastLineInt = false;
was2ndLastLineInt = false;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  if(wasLastLineInt){
     //do something with line if lastline was an int
  }
  else{
    //do something with line if last line wasn't an int
  }
  //whatever other conditions you want

  //prepare for next iteration
  was2ndLastLineInt = wasLastLineInt;//condition of lastline will be condition of 2ndlastline next iteration
  wasLastLineInt = line.matches("^-?\\d+$");//set last line condition for next iteration
}
```

It uses a regex http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html to check if the string is a positive or negative integer.  however it wont catch something with a '+' sign at the front.

Make sure to update the state after you decide how to handle the current line, or you will make decisions based on the wrong lines.  And keep in mind how you want to handle the first few lines, this starts with the behavior for lines -1 and -2 being nonintegers.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but I'm not sure how to track the previous line. Can you show me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The strategy here would be:

Save both the previous line and the current line in memory. You can declare 2 properties on the class handling the file read.

```
private String prevLine;
private String currLine;
```

Then read file lines one by one:

```
...
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    //update line properties
    prevLine = currLine;
    currLine = line;
    if(someConditions(prevLine)){
        handleCurrLine(currLine);
    }
}
```